# Python: Reference forked project in requirements.txt

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a Python project which uses an open source package registered as a dependency in `requirements.txt`

The package has some deficiencies, so I forked it on Github and made some changes. Now I'd like to test out these changes by running my original project, but I'd like to use the now forked (updated) code for the package I'm depending on.

The project gets compiled into a Docker image; `pip install` is used to add the package into the project during the `docker-compose build` command.

What are the standard methods of creating a docker image and running the project using the newly forked dependency, as opposed to the original one? Can requirements.txt be modified somehow or do I need to manually include it into the project? If the latter, how?

Comment: Upload your modified version to pypi then the requirements.txt use your own package. Or in `RUN` of dockerfile, use code to change the original package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `git+https://github.com/...../your_forked_repo` in your `requirements.txt` instead of typing `Package==1.1.1`